# Keep the record current after inserting a new record in form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form based on a table but I also have some extra options on the same form. I want to keep the record selected after insert so I can set some other options in another table. I tried doing this with VBA After Insert but the form blanks out after that subroutine has ended.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
End Sub
```

I know my gotorecord works because I can run it manually and it does select the last record. The problem is that there is a form clear that runs after the "AfterInsert". How do I stop it?

Comment: Please specify how you're doing the insert. By default, when inserting a record, Access doesn't move the selected record at all.

Comment: It's a form for a user to type data in to fields. When you press ENTER to complete the record it moves to a new blank record. This makes sense if you are entering multiple records at once but not if you want to stay on that new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that controls this is the [`Form.Cycle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.cycle) property.

Set that to *Current Record (1)* and pressing enter or tab on the last field will move you back to the first field again.

Do note that enter doesn't save the current record, it's just an alternative for tab. If you want to save the record when leaving the last field, you can use VBA for that.

Comment: This is the correct answer but I had a button with the default property set intercepting the ENTER key.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using some DoCmd commands to insert the records.

Use the *RecordsetClone* and nothing will move - and the form will display the new record if a new record can be seen:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("First Fieldname").Value = some value
    rs.Fields("Second Fieldname").Value = some other value
    ' etc.
rs.Update
rs.Close
```

**Edit**:

To stay on the current record:

Go to the form's *Properties*, tab *Other*, set *Cycle Property*: Current record

Comment: No, sorry. I am talking about a data entry form.

Comment: So enter manually, press Enter saving the record, current record moves to the next (new) record, but you wish to stay on the record just inserted?

Comment: Then my edited answer should work. I can't think of other options.